# Get the posted data from Form in Zend Framework 2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

Im new to Zend Framework, so asking a basic question. I want to get the posted data, in general from one field in a form, I wanted to get the data for debugging purposes.

For example I have a form with fields like username, age and so on. In my controller in addAction(), I want to fetch the username, store it in a variable and use it for debugging purposes. I hope I made it clear. In case if my question is unclear then please do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're not very clear so I suggets a few solutions...

If you need the plain POST value, you can access it using

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
```

From the controller's context.

If you need the value from the form which has been assigned previously, you can access it using

```
$form->get('elementName')->getValue();
```

However, if you're using InputFilters, you need to fetch it using

```
$form->getInputFilter()->getValue('name');
```

Otherwise, the value you're retrieving was not passed through the filters.

Comment: thanks Daniel `$this->getRequest()->getPost('name');` was the one whic I was looking. Accepted your answer :)

Comment: The question not been 'very clear' gave me useful information I have been looking for! Thanks guys!

Comment: thank you for providing two solutions.:) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the following way:
in your controller action

```
$value = $form->getValue('UserName');
```

in this way you can get the value of zend textbox having ID 'UserName'

For more details you can study the code given on :
[Zend Framework Tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Comment: Your answer probably belongs to ZF1, however, OP asked for ZF2.