# Get input value in view Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I created a form input

`$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'UserRestorePassword.Restore',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
                'style' => 'padding: 7px 35px;'
            ),
        ));`

And this generates:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="padding: 7px 35px;" value="Restore">
```

In view:

```
 <?=$this->translate($this->formSubmit($form->get('submit')));?>
```

How to get `Restore` value from this form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the `value` attribute of the `submit` element, call the `getValue` method for that element

```
$value = $form->get('submit')->getValue();  // = UserRestorePassword.Restore
```

Answer (score 3):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367718/468891 :

> If you need the value from the form which has been assigned
>   previously, you can access it using
>
> $form->get('elementName')->getValue(); However, if you're using
>   InputFilters, you need to fetch it using
>
> $form->getInputFilter()->getValue('name');
>
> Otherwise, the value you're retrieving was not passed through the
>   filters.

Comment: Whenever you display form element values which have already been submitted by user make sure you use **$form->getInputFilter()->getValue('name')** otherwise you can introduce an **XSS attack**. Our security team has just found this vulnerability because I wasn't doing this and this is how I have fixed it.