# Fields in a form behave like "required", although they are not

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I am trying to set up an edit form for an entity (*Place*) in my app. For this purpose I have written the form (*PlaceForm*), fieldset (*PlaceFieldset*), .phtml pages and functions in the controller. Since I am new in zf2, I have concentrated on the tutorlias on their homepage. I have seen that from validation is provided by the framework but in my case it is not necessary. None of the fields added in the fieldset have not the required attribute, however when I submit the form under all empty fields I get the message "Value is required and can't be empty" although it is actually not required. I do not want to create a wall of code in this question, so I will start with the function from the controller. If there is someone who would like to help me with this issue, just let me know and I will update any other part of the code (form, fieldset etc.) Thx in advance.

```
...
public function editPlaceAction() {
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $uiServiceProvider = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FamilyTree\Service\UiServiceProvider');
    $placeArray = $uiServiceProvider->fetchSinglePlaceById($id);

    $place = new Places($placeArray);
    $form = new PlaceForm();
    $form->bind($place);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            var_dump($place);
        }
    }

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form,
        'title'=>"Edit place"
    ));
    $view->setTemplate("family-tree/family-tree-maintenance/editPlace");

    return $view;
}
...
```

and here you can see how my Fieldset looks like

```
<?php

namespace Places\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class PlaceFieldset extends Fieldset {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct('place');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'Hidden',
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'admUnit1',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'AdmUnit1',
        ),
    ));

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use '$form->isValid() '. This will validate fields automatically i think. You do not have InputFilter already.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. I removed $form->isValid() and it is true, the fields are not "required" any more but there is other problem now. My place object is not updated with new values from the form. I thought, that it is carried out in background by the framework itself. How can I extract new values from the form after submit, any idea? Thx!

Comment: You can get new values directly from request object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367153/get-the-posted-data-from-form-in-zend-framework-2